# What are the ways to write a sql script for getting mismatch between source and target datatype

Tags: oracle, plsql

Currently I am using

```
(select 'S',DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH from all_tab_columns where table_name like '&Source_Table' and column_name='&Source_Column'
minus
select 'S',DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH from all_tab_columns where table_name like '&Target_Table' and column_name='&Target_Column')
UNION ALL
(
select 'S',DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH from all_tab_columns where table_name like '&Target_Table' and column_name='&Target_Column'
minus
select 'S',DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH from all_tab_columns where table_name like '&Source_Table' and column_name='&Source_Column')
```

But above query need to run for each and every table. So i want to write a script which will use table and column names from a file/one time entry which will fetch mismatches between source and target.

Comment: _"sql script"_ **SQL*Plus** script ? Or are you targetting an other client ? Or are you looking for a stored function (as this question is taggeg as `plsql`) ?

Comment: anything is fine. I will be running on Toad

Comment: How many table/column names do you have to read?

Comment: Let me give example which i want to read. Say there are 3 tables A,B and C. Table A has 5 columns, B has 8 columns and C has 10 columns. Now for each single table and per column I need to execute above query. So to overcome this routine I want to write a script which will takecare for all tables and columns in one execution itself. You might be thinking why i want to do this. Because I am DB tester, i want to know, my source and target column datatype are in sync so that there will be no truncation of data. Hope I answered your quest.

Comment: do you want to compare the actual content of columns of various tables?

Comment: Not content. Hol, I want to verify datatype of the columns between source and target